# Using the $# operator

Tags: perl

I've just taken over maintenance of a piece of Perl system. The machine it used to run on is dead so I do not know which version of Perl it was using, but it was working. It included the following line to count the lines in a page of ASCII text

```
 my $lcnt = $#{@{$page{'lines'}}};
```

In Perl 5.10.1 ( we are now running this on CentOS 6.3 ) the above code no longer works. I instead use the following, which works fine.

```
my @arr = @{$page{'lines'}};
my $lcnt = $#arr;
```

I'll admit my Perl isn't great but from what I can see the first version should never have worked as it is trying to deference an array rather than an array ref

First question - is my guess at why this first line of code doesn't now work correct, and secondly did it work earlier due to a now fixed bug in a prior Perl version?

Thanks!

Comment: $# gives you the last index of an array... if your array contains lines, $#arr is the number of lines -1. here you should consider using scalar which returns the number of elements in an array.

Comment: is `$page{'lines'}` an array or a reference to one?

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean?  The original code isn't a syntax error — what does it do now (I'd guess it returns -1), what did it used to do, and how do you know?

Comment: `use strict` will give you the fatal error `Can't use string ("3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use`.

Comment: This *did* work prior to 5.10, even with strict. I doubt it was ever *meant* to, but you can test it. It compiles, runs, and gives the right answer on perl 5.8.8.

Answer (score 3):

The first version never worked. Assuming `$page{'lines'}` is an arrayref, this is what you want:

```
my $lcnt = $#{$page{'lines'}};
```

Note that this is going to give you one less than the number of items in your arraref. The `$#` operator is the INDEX of the last item, not the number of items. If you want the number of items in `$page{'lines'}`, you probably want this:

```
my $lcnt = scalar(@{$page{'lines'}});
```

Comment: Using `scalar()` in a scalar assignment is redundant. But +1 for correct answer.

Comment: @TLP thank you for the comment. While you are technically correct, I chose to use scalar() in this case to make my intent explicit. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Some things about your code. This:

```
my $lcnt = $#{@{$page{'lines'}}};
```

Was never correct. Take a look at the three things going on here

```
$page{'lines'}   # presumably an array ref
@{ ... }         # dereference into an array
$#{ ... }        # get last index of an array ref
```

This is equivalent to (continuing on your own code):

```
my @arr = @{$page{'lines'}};
my $foo = @arr;                 # foo is now the size of the array, e.g. 3
my $lcnt = $#$foo;
```

If you use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Which you should always do, without question (!), you will get the informative fatal error message:

```
Can't use string ("3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

(Where `3` will be the size of your array)

The correct way to get the size (number of elements) of an array is to put the array in scalar context:

```
my $size = @{ $page{'lines'} };
```

The way to get the index of the last element is using the `$#` sigil:

```
my $last_index = $#{ $page{'lines'} };
```

As you'll note, the syntax is the same, it is just a matter of using `@` or `$#` to get what you want, just the same as when using a regular array

```
my $size = @array;
my $last = $#array;
```

So, to refer back to the beginning: Using *both* `@` and `$#` is not and was never correct.

Comment: Actually it *did* work in the past (tested on 5.8.8), possibly through the same oddity that made `@arr->[2]` synonymous with `$arr[2]`. But it certainly wasn't ever *right*.

Comment: @hobbs Since you are the one with the answer the OP likes best, perhaps you should post an answer that he can accept.